# change JSON prompt description in formflow-json-schema

Tags: json, botframework

In formflow-json-schema I want to add next description

> Your last Order has the following details

for my Prompt **CustomerOrders**, but currently it is using from EnumSelectOne "Please let me know the customer orders:"

**JSON**

```
"required": [
"CustomerOrders",
],
"Templates": {
"NotUnderstood": {
  "Patterns": [ "I do not understand \"{0}\".", "Try again, I don't get \"{0}\"." ]
},
"EnumSelectOne": {
  "Patterns": [ "Please let me know the {&}: {||}" ],
  "ChoiceStyle": "Auto"
}
},
"properties": {

  "CustomerOrders": {
    "Templates": {"NoPreference": { "Patterns": [ "None" ] }},
},
  "type": [
    "string",
    "null"
  ],
   "Define": "return await dllOrders (state,field);"

  },
```

[image: this is sample of problem]

Comment: I don't think this is valid JSON. What exact problem are you having?

Comment: It is just relevant part of full JSON file. I need to put "Your last Order has the following details" as part of prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the Prompt property.

```
 "Length": {
      "Prompt": {
        "Patterns": [ "What size of sandwich do you want? {||}" ]
      }
```

Comment: I tried but prompt did not displayed with define property.

Comment: Any ideas? Prompt can't be dynamically creates, that's is why I used templates.

Comment: Maybe you can try with the Describe parameter. In c# you were not able to do it?